# how to get an index and use it in query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

```
   memberID  |    clubIDs     |       clubRegistrationDates     ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   2             3,4,10,2             2010,2011,2015,2014       ...
   3             2,1,5,6              2015,2000,2005,2010       ...
   4             3,2                  2014,2014                 ...
```

Meaning of a row is, for example: member **2** was registered to club **3** in **2010**, was registered to club **4** in **2011** and so on...
So the query I want to get is to get **any** member who is a member of club **2** since **2014**, so this query should get me members **2** and **4**. I already have an sql but it is not connected to year parameter which is:

```
SELECT clubID, clubName,
(SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',clubIDs) AND status='1' AND memberTypeID='2') AS activeNumber,
(SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',clubIDs) AND status='0' AND memberTypeID='2') AS inactiveNumber
FROM clubs;
```

So I need to get club 2's index from **clubIDs** column and use it for **clubRegistrationDates** column. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should pass just `2` (as integer) not `"2"` (as string) and may be put `> 0` after `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: Actually you should really, really change your DB design. Never store multipe values in a single column.

Comment: I agree with @juergend, but sometimes its impossible to change if the system is already built and there is not enough time available to undertake this kind of major change. Once I have experienced such one :(

Comment: juergen d, a person can be a member of 20 clubs, or 1 club and there is no way of knowing that, therefore, putting 20 columns is not good either and this is a lot more dynamic. For 1 club members, other 19 columns would be null... maksbd19, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never store multiple values in a single column. This will only get you problems like yours now. A better table design would be

```
members table
-------------
id
name
...


clubs table
-----------
id
name
...


club_members table
------------------
club_id
member_id
registration_year
```

It is called a *m to n relation*. Then to get all members of club with `id=2` since `2014` you can do

```
select m.id, m.name
from members m
join club_members cm on cm.member_id = m.id
where cm.club_id = 2
and cm.registration_year = 2014
```

And if you only have the club `name` and not the  `id` then use

```
select m.id, m.name
from members m
join club_members cm on cm.member_id = m.id
join clubs c on cm.club_id = c.id
where c.name = 'Cool Club'
and cm.registration_year = 2014
```

Comment: Yeah, that design is better. The query I wanted would be easier too. Thanks.